# How to make ray coordinate data compatible with rendering in ThreeJS without offset at different ends

Tags: javascript

This issue occurs when using THREEKS to create a dxf/image editor.

One of the functions is the point measurement function. You need to press the mouse in the canvas area to obtain the offsetW/H of that area, then convert it to the standard device coordinates, and use raycaster. setFromCamera (standard device coordinates, camera) to locate the clicked point (because a plane with a width of 10000000 and a height of 100000000 has been added inside the canvas, which is the intersection point of the ray and this plane), and obtain the ray coordinates of the point based on this point. Then render CircleGeometry to the specified location based on the ray coordinates.

The problem is here....

If we save this ray coordinate and render CircleGeometry on another device with inconsistent screen size, there will be a deviation in the rendering position of CircleGeometry. How can we solve this problem?

Based on the above issue, I suspect that the screen size of ThreeJS has changed due to devices of different sizes. Therefore, I calculated the ratio based on two different screen sizes, corrected the ray coordinates based on this ratio, and then rendered.

Result: The satisfactory effect was not achieved, and the deviation still exists

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.